# General solution to the eigenvalue problem of a $3×3$ symmetric Hessian defining curvature

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, hessian-matrix, submanifold

The symmetric Hessian for an implicit surface defined from a field variable $c(x,y,z)$ in Cartesian space is,

$$ \nabla^2 c = \begin{bmatrix} 
c_{xx} & c_{xy} & c_{xz} \newline
c_{xy} & c_{yy} & c_{yz} \newline 
c_{xz} & c_{yz} & c_{zz} \end{bmatrix} $$

such that, $c_{ij} = c_{ji} = \frac{\partial^2c}{\partial i \partial j}$. The characteristic equation $\text{det} (\nabla^2 c - \lambda I) = 0$ of the Hessian then becomes,

$$ \begin{array}+
+\lambda^3  \newline
-\lambda^2 (c_{xx} + c_{yy} + c_{zz}) \newline 
-\lambda\phantom{^1}   (c_{xy}^2 + c_{xz}^2 + c_{yz}^2 - c_{xx}c_{yy} - c_{xx}c_{zz} - c_{yy}c_{zz}) \newline
+\phantom{\lambda^0} (c_{xy}^2 c_{zz} + c_{xz}^2 c_{yy} + c_{yz}^2 c_{xx} - c_{xx}c_{yy}c_{zz} - 2c_{xy}c_{xz}c_{yz}) = 0
\end{array} $$

Given that the Hessian is symmetric such that the eigenvalues are real, what is the general solution of the characteristic equation assuming that it exists?

Are the eigenvalues of this Hessian at a critical point $\nabla c = 0$ the principal curvatures at that location?

Comment: What is an implicit surface? If you mean the set where $c=0$, note that this set need not be a surface near a critical point of $c$. Normally, we assume that $\nabla c \ne 0$ at every point on the set, to ensure it is a surface. Regarding your last question, note that a surface has only 2 principal curvatures, not 3.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I am analysing topology on a 3D iso-surface extracted from a field variable $c(x,y,z)$. That is, a particular  $c = c^*$ value defines a surface. At each grid location where $\nabla c \neq 0$, I can compute principal curvatures (details [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cagd.2005.06.005)). The surface can also self-intersect (critical points) where topology is defined by the eigenvalues of the Hessian which I can compute numerically but want to know if a general analytical solution to the characteristic equation can be formulated.

Comment: If near a point the set $c=0$ consists of two surfaces crossing and the two normals are linearly independent, then the best case scenario is that $c$ factors, $$c=c_1c_2$$ where each factor has nonzero gradient. If you multiply together the second order Taylor polynomials of the factors, you can see where the second fundamental forms of the surfaces at the intersection appear in the 3rd order Taylor polynomial of $c$.

Comment: I also see that you’re at Rice. Have you tried talking to someone in the math department about this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. All I am looking for at the moment is to see whether it is possible to find a general solution to the characteristic equation in the main question. I will try trial and error. Thank you for your help. Also, I am not at Rice - where did you get that from? (-_-)

Comment: Sorry, you cited a paper, and I assumed you were the author, who lists their affiliation as Rice.

Comment: The characteristic equation is a cubic, so you can use the general formula for the solutions to a cubic equation, which can be found on Wikipedia. I was responding to your last question and your comment that the surface has a self-intersection at a critical point. To be more precise, if there is a self-intersection, then $c$ has a critical point there. The converse is not necessarily true. If there is a self-intersection, then there are effectively two or more surfaces crossing at that pont, and there is a second fundamental form for each.